# Proper way of handling payment in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Most of payment frameworks for integration need to create custom form with calculated hash and submiting it to payment server that does redirection.
Generation of form is done on server side (I assume due to security reasons), so example looks like we got kind of php file that calculates hash from input strings (from POST) and document is submited onload event. All works fine.

Now getting into agular world, case seem to be bit different, as most of code is processed on user side. 
Thus question: How to do it properly? Can you share any working sample?

I tried following:
1. prepared php that generates form (that works when php file was directly invoked by browser).
2. In angular applicaiton I have did POST like this:

```
$http({
            method: "post",
            url: "./app/components/db/order.php",
            data: {
                username: $scope.message.username,
                phone: $scope.message.phone,
                // all needed things

            },
        }).success(function (response) {  
            //success
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // failure
        });
```

Main problem here is that php generates document, but it does not seem to be really redirected (at least I dont see this redirection happening in browser).
Can you explain me why it is not working?
Can you advice me how to acheive my goal?

Moreover as I understand any echo done on php side will result in getting into 'success' section from above code.
Is it possible to do POST without getting back to angular?

I was also thinking about following solution:
1. prepare php file that will calculate hash (with private-salt) and return it via json
2. in angular prepare form (exactly same as one that needs to be generated to be sucessfully submited to payment site), with model that is filled once php will return hash
3. do POST to php file, get hash, fill model fields once successful
4. Once model is ready - then submit form.

Question is how to submit form from js in angularjs?
Also I'm not sure if such solution would be secure?

Please be patient I'm novice in angularjs :)

Anyway. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You have to use a html form with post method**

`<form action="./app/components/db/order.php" method="POSTget">
    <input type="text" name="username" value={{message.username}}/>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value={{message.phone}}/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>`

*you can also hide the form for your security resign and trigger the form submit this form using javascript `document.getElementById("myForm").submit();`*

this code will work because this form will submit the data to the **order.php** but in your code the `$http` is sending a XHR request to the **order.php** which is use to request data from the server, client **browser simply ignore the header eg. `Location: http://www.example.com/` coming from the server to redirect to specified url** so the **redirect is not happening**

Comment: Thank you Nitesh. This seem to be proper way of solving this issue!